# How can I receive events from a Xamarin App into my ASP.NET web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a project using .NET that connects to a SQL database with Microsoft Azure. I have two .NET projects, one is a mobile app using Xamarin, and the other is a normal C# application called `DesktopProgram`.

`DesktopProgram` is too big to run well on a phone. Therefore, I need to leave the UI on the mobile app, and the `DesktopProgram` in the cloud. Both projects will have to communicate with each other, and `DesktopProgram` has to communicate with the SQL Database.

If I make my DesktopProgram an ASP.NET project with all the C# logic, will it be able to send and receive events from the mobile app?

Is there a better way to do this? I need a way to execute the C# code, and get input and send output to the mobile app and SQL database. That means that no UI is needed for the web application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to write webservices and call those web service in mobile app.

Comment: Please refer [Xamarin App Development](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181779/Calling-Web-Services-Programmatically-Using-Csharp) for more details

Comment: Could you be more specific with writing webservices?